# Clip Container with transparent icon

Tags: flutter

I'm wondering what the best approach could be to achieve the effect of the rounded icon button on the bottom right.

Do notice the icon is transparent and reveals the image background.
I tried using the `Stack` widget, but I could not position it properly nor get the color to be transparent.

[image: Wanted Result]

Currently I have this:

```
class Banner extends StatelessWidget {
  final String src;

  const Banner(this.src, {Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AspectRatio(
      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
      child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.network(src),
              LayoutBuilder(
                builder: (context, constraints) {
                  var calculatedOverlay = constraints.maxHeight / 3;
                  return Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                          topLeft: Radius.circular(calculatedOverlay),
                        ),
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      height: calculatedOverlay,
                      width: calculatedOverlay,
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Material(
          type: MaterialType.transparency,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Which results in this:

[image: Result]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don’t you just create an image representing white sector with transparent region on it?

Comment: Just use Photoshop...